# How to increment the value of and attribute in my Model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to do a likes button when one click the button, the likes property of the model increments by one. The model looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = '' )

    def process_likes(self):
        print(self.likes)
        self.likes += 1

    def split_tags(self):
        return self.tags.split()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The function from the view in which I call the method looks like this:

```
def print_hi(request, pk):
    print('Hi there!')
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.process_likes()
    return redirect('blog:post_detail', pk=post.pk)
```

The url correspondig to that view function:

```
path('print/<int:pk>', views.print_hi, name='print_hi'),
```

And the anchor in which I call the url to call the function:

```
<a href="{% url 'blog:print_hi' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn">Soy un botón</a>
```

The process_likes method is the one in charge of increment the counter of likes, but when I call the function pressing a button, it doesn´t increment the count? How can I solve this?

Comment: Please, share the code where you call `process_likes()`

Comment: By the way, if you print `self.likes` before incrementing it, you'll get the old value printed.

Comment: @HuLuViCa Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save `post` after calling `process_likes()`:

```
def print_hi(request, pk):
    print('Hi there!')
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.process_likes()
    post.save()
    return redirect('blog:post_detail', pk=post.pk)
```